# Function getting "IndexError: list index of range" for writing to excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, function, while-loop, index-error

Using python 2.7x: 
I've searched through other questions but could not find anything similar to my functions. I'm writing to an excel spreadsheet. The variable a is not used anywhere else in the whole program. I have tried putting the global variable before the function, inside the function, adding into the function as shown below, changing from for loop to while loop, etc, almost everything as suggested by other posts, but they do not work unfortunately.
Could it be that since I'm using an array, it is affecting the code too?
I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range for this while loop and have no idea how to solve. Thanks so much for your help!

GPA is an array somewhere else in the program.

```
     def function(a):
         while (a <785):
             sheet1.write(a+30,10,GPA[a][0])
             sheet1.write(a+31,10,GPA[a][0])
             sheet1.write(a+30,11,GPA[a][1])
             sheet1.write(a+31,11,GPA[a][1])
             sheet1.write(a+30,12,GPA[a][2])
             sheet1.write(a+31,12,GPA[a][2])
             a = a+2
     function (1)
```

Comment: What language are you coding in?  May want to add appropriate tag?

Comment: Sure, I'm using python 2.7x. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are correct. The problem lies with the array which I've solved it.